# libraries in Tomcat/lib not resolved when deploying using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classpath

I have the following issue.
I have a dao library using the atomikos JTA transaction manager.
Also I have a web project that includes that dao library.
And although the tomcat lib folder includes all the required atomikos libraries, I still need to include the atomikos dependency (maven) with scope compile on the library (such that it is packaged along, or at least Eclipse knows it has to be packaged along).
If the library is not packaged along I get Class not found exceptions when deploying under eclipse/STS.

Since the Atomikos libraries are only required for development environments, I don't want these libraries to have scope compile (or runtime).
How can I change my tomcat eclipse setup such that I can set my atomikos dependencies with scope provided in my dao library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Right click on your project in Package explorer, then Tomcat -> set it like a tomcat project and check if there are all libraries presented?

Comment: Hi John, 
What I've tried doing is setting Targeted Runtime to Tomcat for the web project (and the library).
This adds the tomcat libraries to the project next to Maven Dependencies and JRE.
Unfortunately this didn't help getting:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/transaction/TransactionManagerLookup
Additionally I've added hibernate-3.2.6.jar to my tomcat lib folder.
Then I get:

Comment: I was going to say, after adding hibernate to the lib, I get:
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate TransactionManagerLookup 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup'